# JSON feed breaks when importing any custom.js files

Tags: php, javascript, html, json, instagram

I use the instagram API to have a live feed on my website which can be viewed here @ [The Dirty Cookie](http://dirtycookie.co).

```
<script>

    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: false,
            url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/<?=$user_id?>/media/recent/?access_token=13137.f59def8.1a759775695548999504c219ce7b2ecf",
            success: function(data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < <?=$num_to_display?>; i++) {
            $(".instagram").append("<div class='instagram-placeholder'><a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link +"'><img class='instagram-image' src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url +"' /></a></div>");   
                }     

            }
        });
    });

    </script>
```

This works perfectly...until I add

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery(function($){

                $.supersized({
                    slides  :   [ {image : 'slides\background1.jpg', title : ''} ]
                });
            });

</script>
```

My question is why in the world would adding that js break the JSON feed? Firebug shows that it doesn't even attempt to GET the images from the instagram API. While experimenting, I've found that putting practically any other JavaScript anywhere on the site will break that JSON feed. Any suggestions?

Comment: This might not be relevant to the problem but you have an error in the meta tag viewport at http://dirtycookie.co/preview/index2.php  It should be comma separated rather than semicolon separated. Ideally   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

Comment: Thanks, Jaspal... Seems to be unrelated...

Comment: Where is countdown() located and what does it do?

Comment: countdown can be seen @ dirtycookie.co

Comment: If I add your code from custom.js it says `countdown()` is not defined and I get a reference error.  Another non-relevant very minimal bug, your captcha gives a wrong MIME-type, it says it's text/html.

Comment: @Zombaya, it was in the "Supersized.js" file, i removed that link. I simplified the question above. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Everything is working OK on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U9ZFC/2/  Maybe it can help you figure out what's wrong on your preview.

Comment: @Jeff-Meadows, very strange... if you look at dirtycookie.co/preview , it is working as expected now. I removed the lnk to custom.js and put the relevant code in a `<script></script>` on index.php. Thanks for the help. I'm not sure what fixed it or what the original issue was...

Answer (score 1):

try use full url in image : `slides\background1.jpg`?